# kernel module name with _ and -?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, redhat

Why do I have this names in my redhat 5 server?

```
[root@sanserver ~]# lsmod | grep multipath
 dm_multipath           58969  2 dm_round_robin
 scsi_dh                42561  1 dm_multipath **#Module name with _**
 dm_mod                103569  28 dm_multipath,dm_raid45,dm_snapshot,dm_zero,dm_mirror,dm_log

 [root@sanserver ~]# modinfo dm_multipath
 filename:       /lib/modules/2.6.18-371.3.1.el5xen/kernel/drivers/md/dm-multipath.ko **#name with -**
 license:        GPL
 author:         Sistina Software <dm-devel@redhat.com>
 description:    device-mapper multipath target
 srcversion:     4BAFD78E7E55F1ECEFAE485
 depends:        scsi_dh,dm-mod
 vermagic:       2.6.18-371.3.1.el5xen SMP mod_unload gcc-4.1
 module_sig:      883f350528095c4b83fbebdcf4f8e511246ad0a0aac4dc3d4f69ff19b5be180209ffe5e468361309f5db06e141919e5eb76dbd14e2c5539390c54bd4
```

I got two differents names, but there is not alias, one is dm-multipath and second dm_multipath

Answer (score 2):

You are looking at two different names. The module is called `dm_multipath`, and the file that it is loaded from is called `dm-multipath.ko`. These names need not match — the module would still be loadable (via `insmod`, at least) if you renamed it to `example.ko`, but the module would still internally be called `dm_multipath`.

Comment: but internally how this work? an alternative name inside the modules?